# Find Shortest distance from an array of arrays using php

Tags: php, arrays, swap

I want to compare the distance from array[0] to end of array and display the shortest distance with its key.

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Reduit
                    [1] => Curepipe
                )

```
        [distance] => 14.4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [city] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Reduit
                        [1] => Ebe
                    )

                [1] => Bees Village
                [2] => Phoen Trunk Rd
                [3] => Riv,Phoenix
                [4] => St l Rd
                [5] => Geoes Guibert St
                [6] => Curepipe
            )

        [distance] => 1.4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [city] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Reduit
                        [1] => Riv,Phoenix
                    )

                [1] => St l Rd
                [2] => Geoes Guibert St
                [3] => Curepipe
            )

        [distance] => 3.4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [city] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Reduit
                        [1] => Ebene
                    )

                [1] => Belles Village
                [2] => Phoenix Trunk Rd
                [3] => Riverside,Phoenix
                [4] => St Paul Rd
                [5] => Georges Guibert St
                [6] => Curepipe
            )

        [distance] => 22.4
    )
```

)

i use,

$total = count($array)-1;
    $current = $array[0]['distance'];

```
for($loop=1;$loop<$total;$loop++){

    $next = $array[$loop]['distance'];
    $current = $next;
    $current = $current;

    if ($next>$current){

        print_r($current);

        }
    }


}
```

to get the index of all key, take the first index and compare it to other value using swaping..  but it doesn't work. someone has a fix please. thanks you

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you should not set $current = $next unless it is in the if statement, and it also appears you have an extra } in there. I also believe you want to change your > to a < in your if statement. This way it will tell if $next is the lesser of the two.

Try this:

```
for($loop=1;$loop<$total;$loop++){

    $next = $array[$loop]['distance'];

    if ($next<$current){
        $current = $next;
        print_r($current);

    }
}
```

Hopefully it helps you out!

Comment: i get your point, but i want this condition to display the least distance

Comment: Add this code above the for loop I posted: $current = $array[0]['distance']; I am almost certain this will generate what you want. This will set the first item in the array as the closest. The for loop will then check if the next item is less that the current ($next < $current). If the next is less than the current it is the closer distance so we set the current now equal to the next ($current = $next). This process repeats until the loop has finished.

Comment: yes but i want the last least value it prints all values < current only  $total = count($array);
 $current = $array[0]['distance'];
 for($loop=1;$loop<$total;$loop++){
   
    $next = $array[($loop)]['distance'];

    if ($next<$current){
  
        $current = $next;
  
        print_r($current);
  

  }
}

Comment: move the print_r($current) from inside the if statement to after the for loop